# How to replace Employee Id into warning message

Tags: jsp, struts-1

Based on radio button selection i have to show/hide warning message "Employee {0} do not have modification rights. Kindly contact Admin". This message is present into properties file.

Currently Message is displaying on UI like this "Employee null do not have modification rights. Kindly contact Admin".

Instead of null I have to show employee id in this message.I am using struts.

Below is my code base from jsp.

```
<div id="empId" style="display:none;">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" id="msgBlockWarning">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <td class="warnimg" width="42"><img src="/user/images/msg_warn.gif" alt="Warning" height="40" width="40" border="0"></td>
                 <td class="warn" id="msgBlockWarning-warnText"><b>Warning:</b>
                  <br>
                  <bean:message key="<%=ResourceKeys.EMP_WARNING %>"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

Below code is from ResourceKey.java file

```
 public final static String EMP_WARNING = "EMPLOYEE_WARNING";
```

Below code is from properties file.

```
 EMPLOYEE_WARNING=Employee {0} do not have modification rights. Kindly contact Admin.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Struts. After lot of google I found that, i can do it using below tag.

```
 <bean:message key="<%=ResourceKeys.EMP_WARNING %>" arg0="<%=employee.getObjectId()%>"/>
```